# Magento get session value in foreach select option

Tags: magento-1.9, session

How to get Selected session in under **foreach loop**  select option

```
<?php $tree = $this->helper('techinflo_shop')->getCategoriesDropdown(); ?>

          <?php 
              $categoryvalue = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getCategoryValue();
              $attributeValue = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getAttributeValue();
              $homecityvalue = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getHomeCityValue();
              $subcategoryvalue = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getSubCategoryValue();
          ?> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    var children = $H(<?php echo json_encode($tree['children']) ?>);
    function showCat(obj, level) {
        //hideContent();
        var catId = obj.value;
        level += 1;
        if ($('cat_container_' + level)) {
            $('cat_container_' + level).remove();
        }
        if (children.get(catId)) {
            var options = children.get(catId);
            var html = '<select class="form-control" name="subcategory" required="required" id="cat_' + catId + '" onchange="showCat(this, ' + level + ')">';
            html += '<option value=""disabled selected> Select </option>';
            for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                html += '<option value="' + options[i].entity_id + '" >' + options[i].name + '</option>';
            }
            html += '</select>';
            html = '<div id="cat_container_' + level + '">' + html + '</div>';

            $('sub_cat').insert(html);
        }
    }
    /*window.onload=showContent();  
     function showContent(){
        document.getElementById("default-content").style.display="block";
    }
    function hideContent(){
        document.getElementById("default-content").style.display="none";
    }*/
</script>


<!-- <form  action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('catalogsearch/advanced/') ?>" method="post"> -->
<form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('location/index'); ?>" method="post" id="form-validate"> 
          <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" /> 


          <div class="brand">          
            <?php 
            $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'brand'); 
            $allOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true); 
            ?> 
              <select class="attribute-brand form-control" id="attribute" required="required" name="attribute"> 
                  <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option> 
                  <?php foreach ($allOptions as $instance) {?> 
                  <option value="<?php echo $id = $instance["label"];?>"<?php echo ($attributeValue==$instance["label"])?'selected':'' ?>> 
                  <?php echo $value = $instance["label"];?> 
                  </option> 

              <?php }?> 
              </select> 
          </div> 


          <div class="category">
              <select id="first_cat" onchange="showCat(this, 2)" class="form-control" required="required" name="parentcate">
                  <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
                    <?php foreach ($tree['first'] as $cat): ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $cat->getId() ?>" <?php echo ($categoryvalue==$cat->getId())?'selected':'' ?>><?php echo $cat->getName() ?>
                      </option>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
              </select>
          </div>

          <div class="select-city">
            <select class="form-control" id="mytext1" required="required" name="homecity">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
                <option value="Bangalore" <?php echo ($homecityvalue=='Bangalore')?'selected':'' ?>>Bangalore</option>
                <option value="Calcutta" <?php echo ($homecityvalue=='Calcutta')?'selected':'' ?>>Calcutta</option>
                <option value="Chennai" <?php echo ($homecityvalue=='Chennai')?'selected':'' ?>>Chennai</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div id="sub_cat"></div>
        <!-- <div id="default-content">
    <div id="cat_container_va">
          <select class="form-control" id="mytext">
            <option disabled selected>Select</option>
          </select> 
      </div>
        </div> -->


          <button class="btn btn-success btn-block let-shop" type="submit">Let's Shop</button> 
</form>
```

it always display last value only of that dropdown

Comment: are u trying this  <?php  $attributevalue = Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('attribute');
        $attribute = $attributevalue;
        echo $attribute;?>

Comment: Where i need to use

Comment: can you send session code?

Comment: actually i wnat to under select option out side of that it will print but not in select option

Comment: are you set  data in  custom session?

Comment: Yes it's storing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43171/discussion-between-abdul-and-kothari).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('location/index'); ?>" method="post" id="form-validate"> 
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" /> 
<div class="brand"> 
<?php $attributeValue = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getAttributeValue();?> 
<?php 
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'brand'); 
$allOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true); 
?> 
<select class="attribute-brand form-control" id="attribute" required="required" name="attribute"> 
<option value="" disabled selected>Select</option> 
<?php foreach ($allOptions as $instance) {?> 
<option value="<?php echo $id = $instance["label"];?>"<?php echo ($attributeValue==$instance["label"])?'selected':'' ?>> 
<?php echo $value = $instance["label"];?> 
</option> 

<?php }?> 
</select> 
</div> 
<button class="btn btn-success btn-block let-shop" type="submit">Let's Shop</button> 
</form>
```

Comment: How to add ajax value in session check my updated question   <div id="sub_cat"></div>  how to store this value in ajax

Comment: can you please check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128088/how-to-store-and-display-subcategory-ajax-and-cookie